# The closest point

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

How to place n points in a plane so that the distance between every two points is unique and at the same time we could choose one of them that is the closest for all others n-1 points.

I tried to draw it. But I was able to draw it only for max n=5. I drew two perpendicular lines. One point I was intersection of the lines  and the others points lie on the line so that they formed a quadrilateral and point I was inside. With more points it seems impossible to me but I can't prove why

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "the distance between every two points is unique" seems a void condition. I guess that you can always perturb the points by a tiny amount to achieve it without impairing the "closest" condition.

Comment: Guessing that this should be "for each point A there is another point B that is closer to A than any other".   You need to define more carefully what you mean by unique and by closer - which probably means that you have to define the precision of the numbers you are using - integers, floats, doubles or some magic number limited only by Heisenberg

Comment: I don't think it is possible for more than 6 points. For n=6, you could still place a point and then 5 other around a circle whose center is the 1st one (Plus Yves's perturbation), distributed so that each of them are separated by more than the circle radius. But then, for the 7th, it has to be either further from the center than from another one, or to be closer to another one than the center is

Comment: Without the "all different" contraints, it would be possible to have 6 points forming an hexagon, all at the same distance from the center. But not strictly closer to the center. And with Yves's perturbation (that is with the "all distance different" constraint), that wouldn't do it. So just instinct speaking. But my instinct is that problem is not possible for n≥6.

Comment: Anyway, that's not a coding problem. You should go to math.stackexchange.com for this kind of problem. Someone there will certainly have either proof that I am right or proof of the contrary.